# How to implement hook_webform_validation_validators()

Tags: webforms

While doing validation in a Drupal 6 site, I found it uses the webform module. I just want to apply validation on a specific component.
I googled, but I didn't get any link that would help me with adding a validation hook in a webform.

Can anyone help me with the code to implement for `hook_webform_validation_validators()`?

Comment: you just try based on the options in this page                                              http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/webform_validation/webform_validation.validators.inc/function/webform_validation_webform_validation_validators/6